# Error creating new contact with google API

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-contacts-api

I am using the exact github example https://gist.github.com/lovasoa/9547629 to create a new contact entry in google contacts with my api credentials.

However, I am getting an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\Landshoppe\google-api-php-client-2.0.1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\Landshoppe\google-api-php-client-2.0.1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #1 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\Landshoppe\google-api-php-client-2.0.1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #2 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\Landshopp in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\Landshoppe\google-api-php-client-2.0.1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187

If someone can give a quick fix, it would be great !